# How to sort DropdownData by ascending or desc order in angular material mat select?

Tags: angular

how to sort alphabetically array

```
<mat-form-field">
                <mat-select placeholder="Select Service">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let service of servicecalldropdowns" [value]="service.ServiceCall" 
                  (click)="selected($event,service,service.ServiceCall)">
                  {{service.ServiceCall}}</mat-option>  
              </mat-select>
```

Comment: You don't need sortComparator input to sort the data you can sort your data direcly inside getServiceside drop down method like this.serviceCallDropdowns.sort((a,b)=>a.ServiceCall > b.ServiceCall)

Comment: it showing an error on sort function: "property 'sort' doesn't exist on Servicecalldropdown"    and i set modal class for it "public servicecalldropdowns: Servicecalldropdown;'

Comment: What is the response you getting from getservic method?

Comment: Sort method only work with array!